# How to inspect the in-memory Activiti H2 database?

Tags: activiti

I'm just getting started using Activiti, and I'd like to be able to examine the contents of the in-memory H2 database as I run my workflows.  How can I do so?  Is it possible using a tool like Squirrel?  If so, what do I use as a URL, user, password, etc.?  Right now, I am using the default configuration.